# Equivelant for [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"GMT"] in swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nstimezone

---

I need to know the equivalent syntax for `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"GMT"]`
in swift

Comment: I figured it out

var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()  
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT");

Comment: Did you have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/index.html)? It shows both Swift and Objective-C methods

Comment: yes thanks Martin I found it .

Comment: Yep, that's precise translation of that code. Or you can use `formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)`, too.

Comment: Given that you've answered your own question, I might suggest just deleting this question. If it was likely to be of value to future readers, you might [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but in this case, I'd suggest just deleting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
let dateFormatterUTC = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterUTC.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```